# Laravel displaying data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let me explain situation first.

I am on the page with list of skills available such as "Plumber","Carpenter" and "Painter", when I click on one of those skills I want to get a list of handymans that have that skill and once clicked on a handyman I get full details about him.

Skills are displayed however when I click on one of the skills it doesn't want to retrieve any data. Both tables "handymen" and "skills" have many to many relationship and also there is a junction table. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('home', 'HandymanController@home');

    Route::get('search', 'HandymanController@search');

    Route::get('details/{handyman}', 'HandymanController@details');

    Route::post('assignjob', 'HandymanController@assignJob');

    Route::get('addjob', 'HandymanController@addJob');

    Route::post('addjform', 'HandymanController@addjForm');

    Route::get('jobs', 'HandymanController@jobs');

    Route::get('jobsdetails/{jobId}', 'HandymanController@jobsdetails');

    Route::get('deletejob', 'HandymanController@deleteJob');

    Route::post('deletejform', 'HandymanController@deletejForm');
```

Add Job View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Add Job')
        @section('header2')
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{url('assignjob')}}">Assign job</a></li>
            </ul>
        @show
@section('content')
    <h1>Handyman details</h1>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($handymen as $handyman)
   <a href= "{{ url("HandymanController@details", $handyman->id) }}">
      {{$handyman->name}}
   </a>
@endforeach
    </ul>
```

Controller:

```
    function search()
    {
        $skills = Skill::all();
        return view('layouts/search',['skills' => $skills]);
    }
function details($skillId)
{
    $skill = Skill::find($skillId);
    $handymen = $skill->handymen;
    return view('layouts/details', ['handymen' => $handymen]);
}
```

Comment: Can You show what is inside `routes.php` also please provide skills view.

Comment: ok I have updated my post, all the views are included that are relevant to skill search and display, unless u require physical view?

Comment: I already see one problem: your route accepts only one parameter, but method `details` requires two - `Route::get('jobsdetails/{jobId}', 'HandymanController@jobsdetails');`. But can You attach `layouts/search` view?

Comment: job details only need 1 parameter, but details\{skillId} need another one which is {handyman_id} however that doesn't solve issue, it might be something with database maybe? ok I have attached that view

Comment: I did a mistake - pasted wrong line. I talked about `details` method route. Route accepts only one parameter and You are sending only one to it, but method requires two. You are trying to get `Handyman` without providing id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your edited question, first you list all the skills in your search view. So, in your search view, you would have something like this:

```
@foreach ($skills as $skill)
   <a href= "{{ action("HandymanController@addjForm", $skill->id) }}">
      {{ $skill->name }}
   </a>
@endforeach
```

So you have to define in your routes file this route:

```
Route::post('addjform/{skill}', 'HandymanController@addjForm');
```

This will point to Handyman Controller, where you will list all handymen that have that skill:

```
public function addjForm(Request $request, Skill $skill)
{
   $handymen = $skill->handymen;
   return view('layouts/skilledHandymen', ['skill' => $skill,'handymen' => $handymen]);
}
```

For this to work, you have to define in Skill Model, the association:

```
public function handymen()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Handyman::class,
                            'handyman_skill',
                            'skill_id',
                            'handyman_id');
}
```

The controller will point to a view where you will list all handymen that have such skill:

In your case, it would be easier if you define an association in Skill model that links to Handyman:

```
@foreach ($handymen as $handyman)
   <a href= "{{ action("HandymanController@details", $handyman->id) }}">
      {{ $handyman->name }}
   </a>
@endforeach
```

When you choose a handyman, it will take you to Handyman controller details:

```
function details(Request $request, Handyman $handyman)
{
    return view('layouts/details', ['handymen' => $handymen]);
}
```

For this you will define this route:

```
Route::get('/handyman/{handyman}', 'Handyman@details');
```

And this will point you finally to the details of chosen handyman, and you can show his details:

```
<p>{{ $handyman->id }}<p>
<p>{{ $handyman->name }}</p>
```

The thing that is important to understand here is that you will first have a Collection of skills that will lead you to a Collection of Handymen, and not just a single one. After you choose a Handyman from the second list you will be able to show his details. If you try to jump over this step you will be trying to show details of a list.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ok I understand what is happening here, but I would have to update details page, to list these handymen as at the moment's it's only giving me skill name         <li>{{$skill->skill}}</li>. How would I update it? i.e. display first_name from handymen table

Comment: To show every handymen, you should make a view where `$handymen` is listed with a `@foreach($handymen as $handyman)`, and then link each one to a details view through `handyman_id`. This would be easier.

Comment: ok I am waiting for you to edit the answer to include that and I will be happy! Thanks in advance, took my ages to try and figure it out

Comment: No problem! Check the answer again and tell me if it is helpful.

Comment: Ok this is what I get and when I click it, id does change but I do not get output of handyman details http://screenshot.sh/owjmEZKRXJxA1

Comment: But, anyway, the answer is based in creating a view in the middle of "listing skills" and "show details". I would be something like "SkilledHandymen". In this view you have a foreach where you list all Handymen that have that skill. If you call details right after clicking in a view, you will have a list, and not a single handyman.

Comment: I will update my question with code I have at the moment, I get page without any handymen when I click on the skill, something I probably messed up, still new to laravel. I want to keep everything on details page if that is possible

Comment: Ok, check the new answer... I hope this helps you

Comment: Now when I have done this:    @"foreach ($skills as $skill)
   <a href= "{{ action("HandymanController@addjForm", $skill->id) }}">
      {{ $skill->name }}
   </a>
@"endforeach                            I do not get any results at all why?

Comment: You will have no results in this case if you have no skills in your Database, or if the field `name` does not exist, so it will be all blank.